# Entity Framework Many To Many exception with inheritance

Tags: entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-6

I am trying to create two many-to-many relationship maps on a Record object:

Record object that is inherited from

```
public class Record {
    public virtual ICollection<Language> SourceLanguages { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Language> TargetLanguages { get; set; }
}
```

Second Object

```
public class Language
{
    public int Language { get; set; }
    public string Locale { get; set; }
    public string LanguageName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Record> Records { get; set; } 
}
```

Map for Record

```
public class RecordMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Record>
{
      this.HasMany(r => r.SourceLanguages)
            .WithMany(c => c.Records)
            .Map(sl =>
            {
                sl.ToTable("SourceLanguageRecordMap", "dbo");
                sl.MapLeftKey("RecordId");
                sl.MapRightKey("LanguageId");
            });

        this.HasMany(r => r.TargetLanguages)
            .WithMany(c => c.Records)
            .Map(tl =>
            {
                tl.ToTable("TargetLanguageRecordMap", "dbo");
                tl.MapLeftKey("RecordId");
                tl.MapRightKey("LanguageId");
            });
}
```

When I run migration on the object listed above I get the following error:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: Schema specified is not
>   valid. Errors: The relationship
>   'Toolbox.EntityModel.Contexts.Record_SourceLanguages' was not loaded
>   because the type 'Toolbox.EntityModel.Contexts.Language' is not
>   available. ...
>
> Schema specified is not valid. Errors: The relationship
>   'Toolbox.EntityModel.Contexts.Record_SourceLanguages' was not loaded
>   because the type 'Toolbox.EntityModel.Contexts.Language' is not
>   available.

If I comment the following line out, it will work with just **one many to many** map, however, it will add RecordId_Record to Language Table. Any idea why?

```
  this.HasMany(r => r.TargetLanguages)
            .WithMany(c => c.Records)
            .Map(tl =>
            {
                tl.ToTable("TargetLanguageRecordMap", "dbo");
                tl.MapLeftKey("RecordId");
                tl.MapRightKey("LanguageId");
            });
```

Any idea as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 2 Many-to-Many relationships to the same table you need to create 2 separate `ICollection` properties in order for Entity Framework to fully pick up on what you're trying to do. You can't combine them into one, or else you'll get that lovely error that you're seeing there.

Comment: Any idea why I would get null results when I try to query?

Comment: Because it's not pulling anything from the database since the mapping is wrong.

Comment: Is the map itself wrong? Or is it something else? I have two ICollections on the Language.cs now.

Comment: I have no idea. You should probably make that a separate question, though.